# How to find an id in an array in mongoose using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data something like below:

```
{
        "_id": "60708607143b058e101fc189",
        "orders": {
            "userID": "606eaa5cf67ac70cfa347fcd",
            "order": [
                {
                    "productIDs": [ "606f1f37006513258c8b59b9" ],
                    "vendorID": "60641cf597aed2a9a2971a3f",
                    "id": "60708607143b058e101fc18a"
                },

                {
                    "productIDs": [ "606f1fec006513258c8b59ba", "606f2bb2006513258c8b59bd" ],
                    "vendorID": "60642991015028ba0a6ce72c",
                    "id": "60708607143b058e101fc18b"
                }
            ]
        },
}
```

Is there a way to find any given vendorID in this record using nodejs and mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in as a vendor, then you can send the `vendor_id` in the body of the request. To filter all orders associated to that particular vendor, you can try this:

```
Model.find({"orders.order": 
    {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "vendorID": req.body.vendor_id
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't send _id just like that. I can login as a vendor and need to see all the orders associated to that particular vendor.